# Validating list box and radio button in javascript by ID

Tags: javascript

Am trying to validate a listbox and Radio button using by ID, only on  onsubmit.
if I ran in browser it is not showing any alert. When the submit button is clicked, I want to run the script to verify a radio and listbox is selected, if one is selected to do nothing. If one isn't selected I want it to post an alert message.

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8"
    pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<title>Insert title here</title>
<script type="text/javascript">

        function validate()
    {
        if (document.getElementById("drop1").value == "-1")
        {
            alert("please select A");
        }
        if (document.getElementById("drop2").value == "-1")
        {
            alert("please select B");
        }
        if (document.getElementById("drop3").value == "-1")
        {
            alert("please select C");
        }
        if (document.getElementById("drop4").value == "-1")
        {
            alert("please select D");
        }
        if (document.getElementById("drop5").value == "-1")
        {
            alert("please select E");
        }

            var radios = document.getElementsByName("A");
            var formValid = false;

            var i = 0;
            while (!formValid && i < radios.length) 
            {
                if (radios[i].checked) formValid = true;
                i++;        
            }

            if (!formValid) alert("Must check some option!");
            return formValid;
        }

    }
</script>
</head>
<body>
A:<select id="drop1">

    <option value="1">item 1</option>

    <option value="2">item 2</option>

    <option value="3">item 3</option>

    <option value="4">item 4</option>

    <option value="0">All</option>

</select>
 B:   <select id="drop2" >

    <option value="1">item 1</option>

    <option value="2">item 2</option>

    <option value="3">item 3</option>

    <option value="4">item 4</option>

    <option value="0">All</option>

</select>

C:<select id="drop3" >

    <option value="1">item 1</option>

    <option value="2">item 2</option>

    <option value="3">item 3</option>

    <option value="4">item 4</option>

    <option value="0">All</option>

</select>

D:<select id="drop4" >

    <option value="1">item 1</option>

    <option value="2">item 2</option>

    <option value="3">item 3</option>

    <option value="4">item 4</option>

    <option value="0">All</option>

</select>

E:<select id="drop5" >

    <option value="1">item 1</option>

    <option value="2">item 2</option>

    <option value="3">item 3</option>

    <option value="4">item 4</option>

    <option value="0">All</option>

</select>
<input type="radio" id=myradio1 name="A" value="1">one
<input type="radio" id=myradio2 name="A" value="2">two
<input type="radio" id=myradio3 name="A" value="3">three
<input type="submit" value="submit" onclick="validate()">
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Any body to help on this post...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`onsubmit` isn't a valid property for a `input` type, it should be on the `<form>` element :

```
<form method="POST"  onsubmit="validate()">


</form>
```

wrap your code inside the `<form>`

**[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/HhL8G/)**

---

If you don't want to use a `<form>` you should use `onlick` instead of `onsubmit`:

```
<input type="submit" value="submit" onclick="validate()"/>
```

**[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/HhL8G/1/)**

---

If you want to check if any selectbox is selected you can use this:

```
if (document.getElementById("drop1").value == "")
{
   alert("please select A");
}
```

Note that you want a 'placeholder' for your select box that hans't a value. So when the user didn't select anything, the placeholder is selected by default; which hasn't a value.

So when the placeholder is selected a error is thrown

**Html:**

```
 A:<select id="drop1">
    <option value="" style="display: none;">Placeholder</option>
    <option value="2">item 1</option>
    <option value="2">item 2</option>
    <option value="3">item 3</option>
    <option value="4">item 4</option>
    <option value="0">All</option>
</select>
```

**[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/HhL8G/2/)**

I did only one listbox check, you can do the others the same way.

---

Also put your ID names inside a quote:

```
 <input type="radio" id='myradio1' name="A" value="1"/>one
 <input type="radio" id='myradio2' name="A" value="2"/>two
 <input type="radio" id='myradio3' name="A" value="3"/>three
 <input type="submit" value="submit"/>
```

Hope this helped!

Comment: You used a Form ..i want do by ID only without form ..my need when  submit button is clicked at the time it have to selected all or not if its not i have to alert message to user to select list box compulsory ...

Comment: Alright, check another update. It checks if a listbox option has been chosen

Answer (score 0):

`onsubmit` Event can only be set on a `form` element. On the `input` element you can set a `onclick` event.

Comment: how to validate on onclick event for list box and radio button

Comment: You validate it in the click event and then send the data to the server or something

Comment: could able to edit ...and update the script am new and learning on the way the scrip...

Comment: am checking on submit button it all selected or not if its not i have to alert message to user to select list box compulsory ...

Answer (score 0):

You can check value of particular select box:

http://jsfiddle.net/sMNd2/

```
<select id="drop4" >

<option value="1">item 1</option>

<option value="2">item 2</option>

<option value="3">item 3</option>

<option value="4">item 4</option>

<option value="0">All</option>
```

```
$("#selector").click(function() {
alert($("#drop4").val());
```

});

and see which value is selected. Based on that alert the user.

Comment: could u able to do in javascript only when the submit button is clicked, I want the script to verify a radio and listbox is selected, if one is selected to do nothing. If one isn't selected I want it to post an alert message